# Probability of not drawing an element of a certain element in an "binomial drawing" experiment

Tags: probability

I randomly draw 3 elements from a population of 100. What is the probability of a certain element in my whole population *NOT* being including in my drawing?

I know I can draw $C^3_{100} = 161.700$ different ways but the probability mentioned above I cannot compute?

Comment: This looks a lot like a "homework" question but I am actually exploring a Scenario optimization model in which I need to compute these kinds of probabilites

Comment: If you cannot draw the 'certain element', then the favourable draws are $\binom{99}{3}$.

Comment: This follows a simple case of a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) where $K=1$ and $k=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(a certain element is not in draw/sample)=$\frac{{99\choose3}}{{100\choose3}}=\frac{99\times98\times97}{100\times99\times98}=97/100.$